# Google sheet, get value with conditional?

Tags: google-sheets

In column A I have a value of IT, DE or UK (country codes). In column B I have a number (currency value). How do I get the sum of all numbers that have in column A the value of "UK"? Basically I want to get the totals in of column B but grouped by country.

I think DSUM is the correct function to use ?

EDIT Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try and see how it works for you:

```
=query(A2:B, "select A, sum(B) where A <>'' group by A label sum(B) ''", 0)
```

NOTE: depending on your locale you may have to change the first and the last comma to semi-colons:

```
=query(A2:B; "select A, sum(B) where A <>'' group by A label sum(B) ''"; 0)
```

Comment: There is a mistake in your formula.. "Select J" should be followed by a comma like is shown in my formulas..

Answer (score 0):

Two more options:-

A pivot table:

(**Rows** `Country`, **Values** `EUR amount` Summarise by: SUM).

SUMIF:

```
=sumif(J:J,"UK",K:K)
```

The `"UK"` need not be hard coded but say refer to cell Q5:

```
=sumif(J:J,Q5,K:K)
```

Then if Q5 contains `UK` and Q6 `FR` (etc?) the above formula may be dragged down to create a table of results for various currencies. The ColumnQ values might be extracted from ColumnJ, say with:

```
=unique(J:J)
```

in Q4.

(Your locale might require `;` instead of `,`.)